I need to know how to return the numbers assciated with the attached code line
I use this code to create a list of clickable img ids
$('.cycler').each(function() {
  var container = $(this);
  container.append('<div class="cycler_controls"><a href="#" id="pause_resume" class="active">pause</a>');
  for (var j = first_pic; j < last_pic;) {
    if (j < 10) {
      container.find('.cycler_controls').append('<a class="page" href="#" rel="' + '0' + j + '">' + ('0' + j) + '</a>');
    } else {
      container.find('.cycler_controls').append('<a class="page" href="#" rel="' + j + '">' + (j + 1) + '</a>');
    }
    j++
  }

I want to highlight the id associated with each image as the slide show proceeds but don't know how to extract the relevant number or what code I need to use to cvhange each background as the slide show progresses
The show is driven by :
function cycleImages(container) {
  var $active = container.find('img.active');
  var $next = ($active.next('img').length > 0) ? $active.next('img') : container.find('img:first');
  $next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1500, function() { //fade out the top image
    $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
    $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
  });
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    cycleImages(container)
  }, 3000);
  container.data('timer', timer);
}

I think I need code with the above function the sets the relevant cycler_control rel or attr appropriately.
I should add that whilst pretty experience in javascript I am not yet fluent in JQuery!
To see the background of the id nbumber change as the slides do

Aside: Why do you have j++ at the bottom of the loop body, rather than in the for() header?

And if you want to run some code every N seconds, use setInterval() rather than calling setTimeout() repeatedly.

What do you mean by "sets the relevant cycler_control rel or attr appropriately."? How will that cause the image to be highlighted? Just add a class to the relevant element with .addClass(), and use CSS to highlight that class.

Please, take a [tour], then read [ask] and [edit] with a [mre].

Also, avoid using anchors <a> if what your UI needs are <button>s

99% of properly written Slideshows, Carousels, implement a current index that keeps track of the current slide. Having that index you can do everything: from animating (-100% * current), highlighting the slideshow bullets / thumbnails, etc, etc. Clicking Prev, Next you increment/decrement-loop the index, on bullets click you set directly the current index to the bullet index. And then you animate. Simple as that.

Barmar:
1.the j== where it is to deal with 0 as the first image
2. I copied the code so the the setTimeout came with it.
3. I do not want the IMAGE to be highlighted.. just the ID number displayed in the controls list which appears below the image, tells where the show is up to and allows selection if the slideshow is paused

Buijan: I don't need a button. The list of image id numbers is extracted by the code I posted and displayed as a horizontal list beneath the images. I need to highlight the number of the image currently being displayed which is defined by the class "active".
The images are in a stack with the current been made the "active" image

buijan: Everything works as it should and to my satisfaction EXCEPT that the id of the current image is not highlighted. That is what a seek a solution for. I can post a link to an example of the entire working show if that would help.

barmar: I meant 'j++'.  The 'setTimeout' allows the 'speed' of the show to be controlled. setInterval does not seem to work the same way after I tried following your advice

@Faygord If you want commenteers to be notified of DM, use the @ prefix character like i.e: @Barmar - this will notify the OA seiding your comment right in the messages inbox. Otherwise there's no chance anyone will be aware you responded.

@Faygord what are a list of clickable (or even not clickable) images other than "buttons"? please read again all my comments. And Again, please, [edit] to provide a [mre].

https://johnre.es/0001_live/pics/001_master/slide_576_1.html
Is the show with the ID list below the images

@buijan : Thanks for the hint.
To be clear: There are no clickable images. Just elements drawn from the loop through the class that is actually "filled" form a list of images in the document.
I can highlight each number, dbleclick to stop the show and then click to display any image. I simply cannot figurte out how to HIGHLIGHT the number of the image being dispalyed as the show progress. It is a syntax issue I am sure abut as a beginner with JQuery I need advice.!  I didn't write the basic code and am using irt as a tool to learn JQuery

@Barmar: 1.the j== where it is to deal with 0 as the first image 2. I copied the code so the the setTimeout came with it. 3. I do not want the IMAGE to be highlighted.. just the ID number displayed in the controls list which appears below the image, tells where the show is up to and allows selection if the slideshow is paused –
Faygord
Commented31 mins ago   Delete

@barmar: I meant 'j++'. The 'setTimeout' allows the 'speed' of the show to be controlled. setInterval does not seem to work the same way after I tried following your advice

@Buijan:
johnre.es/0001_live/pics/001_master/slide_576_1.html Is the show with the ID list below the images

What I meant was you should write for (var j = first_pic; j < last_pic; j++). It doesn't change how the code runs, it's just the idiomatic way to write for loops.

Please add sample HTML to the code snippets. And use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

@barmar: I get your point and understand the convention re loops. But I have an issue with the fact that arrays have a zero element and don't want that to appear in my list even though i do have an image call 000.jpg. Therefore I increment the loop AFTER the first element is added. But It is only a detail that might be chamnged or resolved later.
johnre.es/0001_live/pics/001_master/slide_576_1.html
is the show with the ID list below the images

The last field in the for() header is executed before repeating, not at the beginning. The two ways of writing the loop are identical.

@barmar: I posted the full slide show so you can see where the controls are I need to highlight during operation.
let me know if you have an issue with it

Please post a [mcve] here, not at an external site. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

If i understood which bit of the code was the problem I would comply.
But I dont.
So shall i post the entire code of the dode as you suggest?
